PyScript not displaying output
I am running a very basic pyscript code that accesses a python file.
The following is the HTML file:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>PyScript Debug</title>
    <!-- Using the latest stable version of PyScript -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.9.1/core.css">
    <script type="module" src="https://pyscript.net/releases/2024.9.1/core.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>PyScript Debugging Example</h1>

    <!-- Terminal display -->
    <py-terminal></py-terminal>

    <!-- Load the main.py file from the server -->
    <script src="https:/vivliosyn.com/python/main_1.py" config ="https:/vivliosyn.com/python/pyscript.json" ></script>

</body>
</html>

'''
The python file - main_1.py - has a single line
'''
print ("1")

'''
Both the HTML and the Python file, as well as the pyscript.json file are store in the same folder on a server (vivliosyn.com/Python).
However, I am not getting the Python file output. I am able to get the output if I directly add the Python code directly to the HTML file. However, I am trying to build an application that has to access a larger python file that is saved as a .py file.

While https://vivliosyn.com/python/pyscript.json really gets me a JSON, https://vivliosyn.com/python/main_1.py results in HTTP 404, so the file is not there.

if you check on https://vivliosyn.com/python/, you will see all three files are there

Yes, later I saw that too, but if you click, it just doesn't get served. It may be something with the web server itself. Perhaps some overzealous security setting preventing it to touch python files, so it won't run unsafe code on the server side.

If you have access to the server itself, check its logs and configuration. If you don't have access to it, a simple hack could be trying a neutral extension, like main_1.txt. That may help with this simple test case, but when you will have multiple files, modules, etc, the original problem will have to be sorted out.

I have access to the server, but not sure exactly what needs to be checked in the logs. pl guide

In PyScript, when you want to load and run an external Python file from a server, instead of using the  tag, you need to use specific PyScript tags. You can use the  tag to directly run Python code in the HTML, and also use other tags to load external Python files.
To load an external Python file, you can use the src attribute inside the py-script 
<py-script src="https://vivliosyn.com/python/main_1.py"></py-script>


this is what I am using

As per my understanding the  tag is used if the python code is directly used within this tags. However, if an external file has to be accessed, then the 
Test PyScript Locally To be sure, try adding your Python code directly inside the HTML file and check if the issue is with PyScript or something else:

    print("1")

If this code works and you see the output "1", it indicates the issue is with loading the external file.
File Accessibility (CORS Issues): If the external file (main_1.py) is hosted on a different domain (vivliosyn.com), you may run into CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues, where your browser blocks the request to fetch the file. Ensure that the server is configured to allow cross-origin requests by enabling the appropriate headers (e.g., Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *).

I have tested by putting the python code - print (1) - directly in the HTML code and it works

All three files - the .py, .html and .json - are hosted on the same server and the same directory . pl see click on https://vivliosyn.com/python/

https://vivliosyn.com/python/main_1.py must open in the browser, but right now it's not opening and giving a 404 error. Please fix this issue."

I have checked, the .py file is ok (it just has 1 line) but the server does not allow opening the code file directly in browser for security reasons.

Pyscript always looks for the source within the project.It can be either a folder or the file and we mention those details in the .toml file or .json file within config tags. For security reasons external source is blocked.
